# Axis of rotate() of css

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I refered the code elsewhere and following the code, it's making a green line square. 
But I think the code has to make a cross not the square.

If I run the code it makes the squre lik the picture below

[image]

It seems that all lines have different rotation axis.
*Can you let me know why it's not making a cross but square?*

**code:**

```js
import styled from "styled-components";

export default function App() {
  const array = [0, 1, 2, 3];

  return (
    <Wrap>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="square">
          {array.map((idx) => {
            return <Line number={idx} />;
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </Wrap>
  );
}

const Wrap = styled.div`
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #111;

  .container {
    border: 3px solid orange;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .container .square {
    top: 200px;
    left: 200px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
  }
`;

const Line = styled.span`
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 10px;
  transform: ${(props) => `rotate(calc(90deg * ${props.number}))`};

  &::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 4px;
    background: #0f0;
  }
`;
```

**CodeSandBox**
https://codesandbox.io/s/zigzag-f2uybc?file=/src/App.js:0-1864

Comment: You have a typo - `.contatiner` - not sure this'll do anything for your issue though.

Comment: it doens't matte but thanks for letting me know a typo

Comment: Why would it make a cross? You literally have a class called square?
To illustrate a bit you can see that transform rotate 90deg will ensure the little square goes in orthogonal angles. Also the keyframes, in which you should have added to your question, with the coordinates: (2px, 2px), (178px, 2px), (178px, 178px), (2px, 178px), (2px, 2px) are travelling through the 4 corners of a square.

Comment: ever used `transform-origin`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Line` component is a square :

```css
  position: absolute;
  inset: 10px;
```

Because without a explicit width and a height, a box in a absolute position with have inferred width from `left` and `right` properties, and inferred height from the `top` and `bottom` properties, so relative to the first parent with a `absolute`, `relative`, `fixed` or `sticky` positioning.

-> `Line` parent is the `<div className="square">` element.
So `Line` will be square.

The reel line is the `Line` before pseudo element :

```css
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 4px;
```

And without positioning (`top`, `bottom`, `left`, `right`), it will start from the top left corner of the first positioned parent.

-> So Every `Line` component is a transparent square with a green line on top.
When you rotating the square by 90°, the line follows, keeping the same position relative to the square.

---

If you want it to form a cross :

You can center the speudo element in the `Line` component, for exemple just add :

```css
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
```

In the CSS of the `Line` component.